# Does Joyal's category $\Theta$ have intersections of active monomorphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Recall that [Joyal's category $\Theta_N$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Theta+category) admits at least two interesting factorization systems:

- **Split epi / Mono.** This makes $\Theta_N$ an elegant Reedy category, with degree function $deg([n \mid \theta_1, \dots, \theta_n]) = n + deg(\theta_1) + \cdots + deg(\theta_n)$.
- **Active / Inert.** Here, a morphism $\phi = [f \mid f_1, \dots, f_m] : [m \mid \theta_1, \dots, \theta_m] \to [n \mid \zeta_1, \dots, \zeta_n]$ is *active* if $f : [m] \to [n]$ is an active map in $\Delta$ (meaning that $0$ and $n$ are in its image) and $f_1,\dots,f_m$ are active in $\Theta_{N-1}$.

Every object $\theta \in \Theta_N$ has a smallest active subobject $\mathbb G_n \rightarrow \theta$ (where $\mathbb G_n$ is a [globe](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/globe) of some dimension), which picks out the pasting composite of all the atomic cells of $\theta$. A morphism $\zeta \to \theta$ is active iff its image contains this maximal pasting composite.

Let $\Theta^{act,mon}_N \subset \Theta_N$ denote the wide subcategory of active monomorphisms.

**Question:** Does $\Theta^{act,mon}_N$ have pullbacks?

**Notes:**

1. When $N = 1$, the answer is *yes*.
2. When $N = 1$, both conditions (monomoprhism + active) are necessary: $\Delta$ fails to have the intersection of the two monomorphisms $[0] \rightrightarrows [1]$, and also fails to have the pullback of the unique map $[1] \to [0]$ along itself (and this map is an active epimorphism).
3. I tried proving the answer is *yes* via a simple-minded induction using the wreath product description $\Theta_N = \Delta \int \Theta_{N-1}$, but this fails because there are active monomorphisms $\phi$ as above whose components $f_i$ are active non-monomorphisms (this happens often when the leading component $f$ is not the identity).
4. I'm already unclear on the answer when $N = 2$. For a first example, consider the two active monomorphisms $[1 \mid 2] \rightrightarrows [2 \mid 1, 1]$. Their intersection exists and is given by the minimal active map $[1 \mid 1] \to [2 \mid 1, 1]$.

(To orient the reader who may need a refresher on the notation I'm using for objects of $\Theta_2$, note that $[2 \mid 1, 1]$ corepresents two 2-cells $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha \circ_0 \beta$ is defined, while $[1 \mid 2]$ corepresents two 2-cells $a,b$ such that $a \circ_1 b$ is defined. The two maps above corepresent the facts that if $\alpha \circ_0 \beta$ is defined, then $(\alpha \circ_0 \partial^-\beta) \circ_1 (\partial^+ \alpha \circ_0 \beta)$ and $(\partial^- \alpha \circ_0 \beta) \circ_1 (\alpha \circ_0 \partial^+ \beta)$ are defined. The map from the intersection corepresents the composite cell.)

Comment: I should note that the active monomorphisms in $\Theta$ are called _inner faces_ by Berger and _tree diagrams_ by Batanin.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but that it might take a lot of works to prove. If I focus on $N=2$ and restrict to the case of objects where $\theta_i > 0 $, then it seems to me this active mono can be described relatively explicitely in terms of some kind of partition of the basic 2-cell of the target (plus some data of how the different part of the partition fits into the 2-cell of an object of $\theta_2$).  It then seem to me that there is an algorithme to compute the "intersection" of two such partition [...]

Comment: @SimonHenry I think such a description of the active monos appears in Remark 3.17 of Berger's [Iterated wreath product...](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512575), if that makes anything clearer.

Comment: [...] Basically, given two partitions you want to take the smallest sets that are union of sets of each partition, and are closed then close these under certain condition that force them to be admissible pasting diagrams... that was already too much work to figure out all the details so I stoped there - and that is already a fairly special case. But at least with that kind of approach you should either find a terminating algortihm, or find a good reason why there might not be an intersection...

Comment: There is no remark 3.17 in Berger's paper ?

Comment: Oh weird -- sorry, Rmk 3.15. Maybe it's not precisely the sort of thing you have in mind though.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I have a counterexample. There are active monos $[2 \mid 2, 1], [2 \mid 1, 2] \rightrightarrows [3 \mid 1, 1, 1]$ picking out $(\beta \circ_1 \alpha) \circ_0 \gamma$ and $\alpha \circ_0 (\beta \circ_1 \gamma)$ (modulo whiskerings) respectively. Here $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the atomic 2-cells of $[3 \mid 1 , 1, 1]$. I think their intersection in $\Theta$-sets has two incomparable maximal $\Theta$-subobjects shaped like $[1 \mid 3]$: $\beta \circ_1 \alpha \circ_1 \gamma$ and $\beta \circ_1 \gamma \circ_1 \alpha$ (modulo whiskerings), respectively.

Comment: Hum.. yes, that works. Interesting, I had completely miss inclusion like that of $\beta \circ_1 \alpha \circ_1 \gamma$ in $\alpha \circ_0 ( \beta \circ_1 \gamma)$ where two cells ($\beta$ and $\gamma$) that were previously directly vertically composed get "separated"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recorded in the comments, the answer is *no*. In the following, I write composition in diagrammatic order. Consider the object

$$X = [3 \mid 1, 1, 1] \in \Theta_2$$

which is freely generated by three 2-cells $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ which are $\circ_0$-composable, so that $\alpha \circ_0 \beta \circ_0 \gamma$ is defined. Let

$$Y \subset X$$

be freely generated by the 2-cells $\beta' = \partial^- \alpha \circ_0 \beta$, $\alpha' = \alpha \circ_0 \partial_+ \beta$, and $\gamma$. So $(\beta' \circ_1 \alpha') \circ_0 \gamma$ is defined; we have $Y \cong [2 \mid 2, 1]$. Let

$$Z \subset X$$

be freely generated by the 2-cells $\alpha$, $\beta'' = \beta \circ_0 \partial^- \gamma$, and $\gamma'' = \partial^+ \beta \circ_0 \gamma$. So $\alpha \circ_0 (\beta'' \circ_1 \gamma'')$ is defined; we have $Z \cong [2 \mid 1, 2]$.

Here are two subobjects of $X$ which are contained in $Y$ and in $Z$. On the one hand, we have

$$A \subset Y \cap Z$$

which is generated by $\bar \beta = \partial^- \alpha \circ_0 \beta \circ_0 \partial^- \gamma$, $a = \alpha \circ_0 \partial^+ \beta \circ_0 \partial^- \gamma$, and $c = \partial^+ \alpha \circ_0 \partial^+ \beta \circ_0 \gamma$. We have that $\bar \beta \circ_1 a \circ_1 c$ is defined, so $A \cong [1 \mid 3]$. On the other hand we have

$$B \subset Y \cap Z$$

which is generated by $\bar \beta$, $c' = \partial^- \alpha \circ_0 \partial^+ \beta \circ_0 \gamma$, and $a' = \alpha \circ_0 \partial^+ \beta \circ_0 \partial^+ \gamma$. We have that $\bar \beta \circ_1 c' \circ_1 a'$ is defined, so that $B \cong [1 \mid 3]$ as well.

For degree reasons, we cannot have a pullback $A \cup B \subseteq P \subseteq Y \cap Z$: if $deg(P) = 4$, then $A \to P$ and $B \to P$ would be isomorphisms, while if $deg(P) = 5$, then $P \to Y$ and $P \to Z$ would be isomorphisms.